# Anaconda does not start all the time (Python 3.5)

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, launch

Anaconda does not start all the time while I keep it up to date.

Here is the latest log:

```
conda update anaconda-navigator
```

It gave the following:

```
environment location: C:\Users\Toly_N\Anaconda3

  added / updated specs:
    - anaconda-navigator


The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

    blas:            1.1-openblas                          conda-forge --> 1.0-mkl
    libxcb:          1.13-hcb389fa_0                       conda-forge --> 1.12-vc14_1           conda-forge [vc14]
numpy:           1.14.5-py36_blas_openblash8d851b4_200 conda-forge [blas_openblas] --> 1.14.3-py36h9fa60d3_2        
python-crfsuite: 0.9.5-py36hfa6e2cd_0                  conda-forge --> 0.9.2-py36_vc14_0     conda-forge [vc14]
rstudio:         1.0.153-1                                         --> 1.0.136-vc14_2                    [vc14]
sqlite:          3.24.0-hb652765_0                     conda-forge --> 3.22.0-vc14_0         conda-forge [vc14]

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: \ DEBUG menuinst_win32:__init__(196): Menu: name: 'RStudio Desktop ${PLATFORM}', prefix: 'C:\Users\Toly_N\Anaconda3', env_name: 'None', mode: 'user', used_mode: 'user'
DEBUG menuinst_win32:create(320): Shortcut cmd is C:\Users\Toly_N\Anaconda3\python.exe, args are ['C:\\Users\\Toly_N\\Anaconda3\\cwp.py', 'C:\\Users\\Toly_N\\Anaconda3', 'C:\\Users\\Toly_N\\Anaconda3\\Library\\bin\\rstudio.exe']
\ DEBUG menuinst_win32:__init__(196): Menu: name: 'RStudio Desktop ${PLATFORM}', prefix: 'C:\Users\Toly_N\Anaconda3', env_name: 'None', mode: 'user', used_mode: 'user'
DEBUG menuinst_win32:create(320): Shortcut cmd is C:\Users\Toly_N\Anaconda3\python.exe, args are ['C:\\Users\\Toly_N\\Anaconda3\\cwp.py', 'C:\\Users\\Toly_N\\Anaconda3', 'C:\\Users\\Toly_N\\Anaconda3\\Library\\bin\\rstudio.exe']
done
```

After that I tried launch again in both: by double clicking and from the prompt but nothing worked.

This happens periodically

Any suggestions? How do I start Python without launching Anaconda?

Comment: Event tried to run as an administrator but still it would not launch